# How to get multiline strings in Examples in Scenario Outline in cucumber tests to work?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I would like to use multiline strings in the Examples section of The Scenario Outline.
How to do that ?

eg

```
Scenario Outline:
  Given something
  When `<action>` happens
    I should get elaborative `<duuh>`
  Examples:
    |action|duuh|
    |"""
    tututuut
    """|"""blablabla m
    ultiline"""|
```

it does not look clean neither works

Comment: That would be useful to us. Now I wont be able to use scenario outlines because multiline strings are not supported there. Instead, lets forget about scenario outlines and copy paste everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prioritize the cucumber *output*, not the Gherkin *input*, although first prize is for both to be beautiful. So multiline example values don't make sense for me, because they absolutely wreck the cucumber output.

Cucumber encourages readable output for multiline data with [doc strings](https://cucumber.io/docs/reference#doc-strings). It encourages readable output for data matrices with [scenario outlines](https://cucumber.io/docs/reference#scenario-outline). I don't think it encourages readable output of multiline data matrices.

If you could come up with great examples of how the output would look in such cases, they might be well received on the [Cukes forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/cukes).

Alternatively, if all you're trying to do is iterate over multiline data in your Cucumber features, come up with mnemonic names for the multiline data, provide those mnemonics in the `Examples` matrix of your `Scenario Outline`, and treat the mnemonics as the names of fixture files that you read for the actual data in your glue code.

Answer (score 1):

What I did, was to separate the long strings in files (in my case it was pieces of json) and when I need the strings, I just load the needed file.

I did it in Grails, but should be very similar:

> Method to read the file

```
static String getMockJsonFile(String fileName){
    new File("${BOOKING_JSON_FILES_PATH}${fileName}.json").text
}
```

> Json file

```
"collectionSummary": {
"attempts": [
{
"collectionMethod": {
"creditCardCollectionMethod": {
"id": 2,
"collectionMethodType": "CREDITCARD",
"creditCardType": {
"code": "CA",
"name": "Master Card Credit"
}
}
},
"billingCurrency": "EUR"
}
],
"creationDate": "2017-05-30 14:46:19",
"currency": "EUR",
"collectedAmount": 9.1
}
```

> If you set """ triple quotes in the file, the string result will have it too.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using \n in your strings to denote the carriage return?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried this, however it does not produce clean code, which is the most import thing for me to have right now.

Comment: I would argue it's cleaner than your current example, but that's OK.  What would you want it to look like?